# How to use retrofit call for this response?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

Response of the API having Get call but how to achieve these values from retrofit Api call in which call is going in the OnFailure function and unable to get respoonse in the Code snippet given after the Response Viz getresponse() function. This function is giving an exception and does not return the values of the Global, Countries and main model class**

```
The response of the API showing the object with key and having the values, how should one use Values of the key as it is not achievable by my java code snippet

                     {
                      "Global": {
                        "New": 118196,
                        "Total": 5898252,
                        "NewD": 4785,
                        "TotalD": 367273,
                        "NewR": 65964,
                        "TotalR": 2415401
                      },
                      "Countries": [
                        {
                          "Country": "Afghanistan",
                          "CountryCode": "AF",
                          "Slug": "afghanistan",
                          "Date": "2020-05-29T08:39:18Z"
                        },
                        {
                          "Country": "Belarus",
                          "CountryCode": "BY",
                          "Slug": "belarus",
                          "Date": "2020-05-29T08:39:18Z"
                        },
                        {
                          "Country": "Brazil",
                          "CountryCode": "BR",
                          "Slug": "brazil",
                          "Date": "2020-05-29T08:39:18Z"
                        }
                        ],
                      "Date": "2020-05-29T08:39:18Z"
                    }


                After making 3 models for this response namely Main, Global, Countries, how to get response values from Global i.e-("New": 118196, "Total": 5898252, "NewD": 4785,"TotalD": 367273,"NewR": 65964,"TotalR": 2415401), Countries({"Country": "Afghanistan", "CountryCode": "AF", "Slug":"afghanistan","Date": "2020-05-29T08:39:18Z"
                        }), and Main class(Countries,GLobal and Date).


                    Here is the java function which is-

                    private void getresponse() {
                            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                                    .setLenient()
                                    .create();
                            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                    .baseUrl(endpointApi.BASE_URL)
                                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))                                    
                                    .build();
                            endpointApi api = retrofit.create(endpointApi.class);
                            Call<List<Main>> call = api.getResult();
                            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Main>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<List<Main>> call, Response<List<Main>> response) {
                                    List<Main> heroList = response.body();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < heroList.size(); i++) {
                                        Integer heroes = heroList.get(i).getCountries().size();
                                        Log.i("test111","test111--"+heroes);
                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    t.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

The above java code is for retrofit for getting the response from the API, how to get TotalD from Global and Slung from Countries object in this code snippet. The above code Shows no response and goes to onFailure() function and unable to get the response fro the API as

```
        Here is the Interface code snippet-
        public interface endpointApi{
            String BASE_URL = "https://api.something.com/";
            @GET("summary")
            Call<List<Main>> getResult();
        }

            **How to achieve all values in Global i.e, Countries, and Main model class values?**
```

Comment: Can you show the errors

Comment: Sorry it's an exception VIZ Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you only want `totalD` from `Globals` and `slug` from countries

```
public class MyResponse {
    private GlobalObj Global; //capital G for variable name
    private List<Country> Countries; //capital C for var name

    //your getter methods here... 
} 

public class GlobalObj {
    private String TotalD; //capital T for TotalD
    //your getter here
} 

public class Country {
    private String Slug; //capital S.
    //your getter
}
```

Then in your `Call` use this as follows:

```
Call<MyResponse> getResult..........
```

Note: The names of your variables must match with those in the response else you'll get null in them. Pay attention to the capital letters of the variable names. 
Or you can use @SerialzedName if you don't want capitals

Comment: why we cannot use`@SerializedName` from gson?

Comment: Of course you can, I've already mentioned it in the note in my answer. You can use either of the way

Comment: artenson.art98 Thanks for this but I have already done that, my code is wrong at this line in code Call<List<Main>> call = api.getResult() as I need to change this to  Call<Main> call = api.getResult(); Which I resolved now. Thanks a lot for the help!!!!!!